# Submit form alerts save dialog

Tags: jquery, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, submit

I have an MVC 3 solution. For submitting the forms we use jQuery.Form library.Everything goes OK on my machine in Firefox, but in IE after submittingthe form I see the save file dialog. What am I doing wrong? What details can I provide to give more info about the issue?

Comment: please provide your code samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form contains file inputs for uploading files and your server returns JSON make sure that the JSON response is wrapped in `<textarea>` tags as [explained in the documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload).

You could for example write a custom action result that will do the job:

```
public class JsonResultWithTextArea : JsonResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Write("<textarea>");
        base.ExecuteResult(context);
        response.Write("</textarea>");
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(MyViewModel model)
{
    ...
    return new JsonResultWithTextArea
    {
        Data = new { foo = "bar" },
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exact thing that helped us, but in a bit another words